# Scope in Rails and nested query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to join self-joins tables in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554579/unable-to-join-self-joins-tables-in-rails)

I have multilevel categories

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  has_many :children,  :class_name => "Category"
  has_many :products
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :parent

end
```

Here is a model of `Product`

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I need to define scope in `Product` to be able to find all products by parent category name

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 #.....
 #scope :of_tea, lambda{ where(:category.parent.name => "tea") } # not working
end
```

Comment: I think you mean to have the foreign key specified in the :children relation, not the :parent.

Comment: I need all products with a certain parent category. It's 'tea'. For example: 'tea/black tea', 'tea/fruit tea'...

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash to specify the where condition:

```
where(:category => { :parents => { :title => "tea" } } )
```

Comment: Nope. `Product.of_tea
2012-09-23 19:30:33 DEBUG --   Product Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `Object`.`name` = 'tea'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'Object.name' in 'where clause'`

Comment: In category, you refer to a "title" column, but in the scope you referred to a "name" column. Is that the issue?

Comment: It's my bad. But it doesn't work either `1.9.3p194 :001 > Product.of_tea
2012-09-23 19:39:14 DEBUG --   Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `Object`.`title` = 'tea'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'Object.title' in 'where clause': SELECT `products`.* FROM `products`  WHERE `Object`.`title` = 'tea'
`

Comment: I really think this is because of your foreign key, as I mentioned in a comment above. `belongs_to :parent` doesn't need `:foreign_key => "parent_id"` because each object already knows to use the parent_id to find the parent in the category table. But `has_many :children` needs the foreign key to know which categories to collect in the Category table. You need to move `:foreign_key => "parent_id"` to the second line.

Comment: I changed it. The same error is remaining. The scope is `scope :of_tea, where(:category => { parent => { :title => 'tea'} } )
`