# Unable to join self-joins tables in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, join

I have 2 models

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category"
  has_many :children,  :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  has_many :products
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :parent

end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

In particular, Category has a parent item titled "tea" and this item has many children items: "black tea", "white tea"...

I need to select products that belong to a **parent** category "tea". Here is how I'm doing that:

```
Product.joins(:category=>:parent).where(:category=>{:parent=>{:id=>1}}).all
```

It throws an exception (unable to format it well)

```
Product Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `products`.`category_id` INNER JOIN `categories` `parents_categories` ON `parents_categories`.`id` = `categories`.`parent_id` WHERE `parent`.`id` = 1

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'parent.id' in 'where clause': SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `products`.`category_id` INNER JOIN `categories` `parents_categories` ON `parents_categories`.`id` = `categories`.`parent_id` WHERE `parent`.`id` = 1
```

because of unknown parent.id column.

Obviously, the query should be (it's working perfect):

```
    SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` 
    INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `products`.`category_id` 
INNER JOIN `categories` as `parents_categories` ON `parents_categories`.`id` = `categories`.`parent_id` WHERE `parents_categories`.`id` = 1
```

I even tried

```
Product.joins(:category=>:parent).where(:category.parent=>{:id=>1}).all
```

and it didn't help

Please, your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the operation of `joins()` here is pretty smart, the `where()` part isn't so clever. AFAIK it doesn't know anything about the joins and really just converts its arguments to strings. As such, try this:

```
Product.joins(:category=>:parent).where(:parents_categories=>{:id=>1})
```

In order to avoid bleeding the name used internally by AR to your code, consider using AREL for your query. There have been some excellent railscasts on that subject recently.