# Self joins in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, join

As I already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554579/unable-to-join-self-joins-tables-in-rails), I have a model titled `Category`

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category"
  has_many :children,  :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  has_many :products
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :parent

end
```

I need to select all **child** `Categories` that have a certain **parent** `Category` with a certain title:

```
Category.where(:category=>{'parents_categories'=>{:title=>'tea'}}) #wrong
```

It's not working as I need. It's not working at all, actually:

```
Category Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `parent`.`title` = 'tea'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'parent.title' in 'where clause': SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories`  WHERE `parent`.`title` = 'tea'
```

I did a research but found nothing. How do I solve it?

**UPDATE**:
I have a need to create a scope in `Category` model which will allow me to make a call: `Category.of_tea` (exactly) and will return all **children** categories that belong to a **parent** `Category` with title '`tea`'.

Answer (score 2):

Add a scope to your category, then use it on your parent object:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category"
  has_many :children,  :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  has_many :products
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :parent

  scope: with_title, lambda{|text| where(title: text) }

end

category = Category.find(65) #you know, or whatever
tea_categories = category.children.with_title("tea")
```

Comment: It's not what I need. Scope is a right approach, but this `category.children.with_title("tea")` looks quite ugly. I'd like something like this: `Category.of_tea`

Comment: Something like `Category.of_tea.with_parent(@parent)`?

Comment: Nope. Exactly `Category.of_tea`

Comment: You absolutely, without question, will need to specify which category for which you want children. There is no way around this.

Comment: Nope, you do not want of_tea here. You want of_tea on different question you asked

Comment: Based on your updated requirements, Mladen Jablanović's answer is correct.